# Strict growth and strict decrease of sequences of intervals in $\mathbb {R}^n$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Show that the sequence of intervals of $\mathbb{R}$ given by $A_n=\left(0,1-\frac{1}{n}\right),n \geq 1$ is strictly increasing and that the sequence of intervals of $\mathbb {R}$ given by $B_n=\left(1-\frac{1}{n},1\right), n\geq 1$ is strictly decreasing.

I tried to solve the problem in the following way, but it is not correct. If there are errors in my attempt, I hope you can tell me what they are and how they can be solved.

//

$A_n=\left(0,1-\frac{1}{n}\right),n \geq 1$

To show that $A_n$ is strictly increasing, one must verify $A_n \subset A_{n+1}$. Let us note that \
$$\left(1-\frac{1}{n+1}\right) - \left(1-\frac{1}{n}\right)= \frac{1}{n\left(n+ 1\right)}>0, \forall n \in \mathbb{N} $$

Then $\left(1-\frac{1}{n}\right) < \left(1-\frac{1}{1+n}\right)$ and so $ A_n \subset A_{n+1} $, that is, $A_n$ is strictly increasing.\\

$B_n=\left(1-\frac{1}{n},1\right), n\geq 1$

Proceeding analogously to the previous point, let us verify that $B_n\supset B_{n+1}$, note that\
$$\left(1-\frac{1}{n}\right) - \left(1-\frac{1}{n+1}\right) )= \frac{1}{n\left(n +1\right)}>0, \forall n \in \mathbb{N} $$

Then $ \left(1-\frac{1}{n}\right) >\left(1-\frac{1}{1+n}\right)$ and so $B_{n}\supset B_{n +1}$, $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}$, that is, $B_n$ is strictly decreasing.

Comment: Aside from claiming both $\left(1-\frac{1}{n}\right) <\left(1-\frac{1}{1+n}\right)$ and $\left(1-\frac{1}{n}\right) >\left(1-\frac{1}{1+n}\right)$, this seems fine to me. Who said it wasn't correct?